# Android SQLite Database Version, changed structure now cannot view DB

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

My SQLite database appears to be entering entries fine however I cannot pull them back to view them, everytime I load the activity my app crashes, Changing the database version throws a SQL exception and force closes the app also.

Below is the class where the SQL is handled:

```
package com.uhi.fatfighter;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Stats {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_WEIGHT = "weight";
    public static final String KEY_WAIST = "waist";
    public static final String KEY_CHEST = "chest";
    public static final String KEY_LEGS = "legs";
    public static final String KEY_ARMS = "arms";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "statsDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "personalStats";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    private DbHelper ffHelper;
    private final Context ffContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ffDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_WEIGHT
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_WAIST + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_CHEST + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_LEGS
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_ARMS + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }

    public Stats(Context c) {
        ffContext = c;
    }

    public Stats open() throws SQLException {
        ffHelper = new DbHelper(ffContext);
        ffDatabase = ffHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public void close() {
        ffHelper.close();

    }

    public long createEntry(String weight, String waist, String chest, String legs, String arms) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_WEIGHT, weight);
        cv.put(KEY_WAIST, waist);
        cv.put(KEY_CHEST, chest);
        cv.put(KEY_LEGS, legs);
        cv.put(KEY_ARMS, arms);
        return ffDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

    public String getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_WEIGHT, KEY_WAIST, KEY_CHEST, KEY_LEGS, KEY_ARMS };
        Cursor c = ffDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iWeight = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEIGHT);
        int iWaist = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WAIST);
        int iChest = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHEST);
        int iLegs = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LEGS);
        int iArms = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ARMS);
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iWeight)
                    + " " + c.getString(iWaist) 
                    + " " + c.getString(iChest) 
                    + " " + c.getString(iLegs) 
                    + " " + c.getString(iArms) + "\n";

        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

and below is the Activity that calls the SQL handling class:

```
package com.uhi.fatfighter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DBView extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_stats);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDBInfo);
        Stats dbInfo = new Stats(this);
        dbInfo.open();

        String data = dbInfo.getData();
        dbInfo.close();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data)) {
            tv.setText(data);
        }


    }



}
```

as i said this was working fine until I added some extra fields

Logcat:

```
05-09 13:44:32.761: E/Trace(7576): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:44:32.894: E/InputDispatcher(1294): channel '415d5068 com.uhi.fatfighter/com.uhi.fatfighter.Splash (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-09 13:44:34.964: E/Trace(7593): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:44:34.988: E/Trace(7598): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uhi.fatfighter/com.uhi.fatfighter.DBView}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4928)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:747)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at com.uhi.fatfighter.DBView.onCreate(DBView.java:16)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
05-09 13:44:54.250: E/AndroidRuntime(7598):     ... 11 more
05-09 13:44:56.765: E/Trace(7630): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:45:10.125: E/Trace(7649): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:45:10.433: E/Trace(7664): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:45:11.183: E/Trace(7678): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:45:12.203: E/Trace(7695): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uhi.fatfighter/com.uhi.fatfighter.DBView}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4928)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:747)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at com.uhi.fatfighter.DBView.onCreate(DBView.java:16)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
05-09 13:45:14.187: E/AndroidRuntime(7630):     ... 11 more
05-09 13:45:18.433: E/Trace(7722): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:52:02.109: E/Trace(7767): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:52:03.554: E/Trace(7781): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:55:06.617: E/Trace(7807): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uhi.fatfighter/com.uhi.fatfighter.DBView}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4928)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:747)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at com.uhi.fatfighter.DBView.onCreate(DBView.java:16)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
05-09 13:55:26.808: E/AndroidRuntime(7807):     ... 11 more
05-09 13:58:40.242: E/Trace(7828): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:58:40.500: E/Trace(7841): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-09 13:58:40.937: E/PhotoDatabaseHelper(7828): query fail: empty cursor: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@415ae7e8
05-09 13:58:40.937: E/WidgetProvider(7828): cannot load widget: 5
```

I can see the class is having trouble casting TextView

Comment: Post the exception. Please.

Comment: Its hard to read as it gets pushed behind the force close message, eclipse shows a syntax error near 'EXIST' and the portion of the error i could get had to do with a syntax error near DROP TABLE IF EXIST

Answer (score 1):

Your drop query is wrong. EXIST is a wrong keyword.

It should be :

> db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

Comment: yeah that fixed the ability to add fields to the DB with the new version number, still cannot view the fields though.

Comment: Most important think when you use such implementation, All the data in database will be lost since you are dropping the Table. Make sure, you have data in the table.

Comment: My insert statement appears to be a success, I have a dialog within a try catch that should catch any errors, when I click 'View DB' however the app force closes

Comment: Please post the log to help u more.

Comment: The error is in LayoutInflater not related to DB or Sqlite. Post R.layout.view_stats layout.

Comment: You're right, the problem was in the layout file, my TextViews weren't closed properly

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
```

is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the XML file for the SQLITE view, I checked all my TextView fields were set up correctly, they weren't. This fixed the issue.